# Should this question be split?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question

A discussion began in the comments on [Can I get an ebook from the library in the United States?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/547/can-i-get-an-ebook-from-the-library) should it be split and the answers that are non-USA be recreated on the splits?

Comment: Just a note that if this is done, the original answers will be deleted and need to be re-entered on the appropriate questions. Likely the original answer poster will want to do it since they are going to lose the reputation once the original answer is deleted. They would also only regain the reputation they lost if they were to receive the same number of upvotes as the original answer. This may or may not be important to some people.

Comment: @JasonDown I believe this can be tagged status completed, only mods can apply the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a Canadian version of the question [here](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/839/are-there-any-ebook-libraries-in-canada). Anyone who answered the original question, but with Canadian answers, I will upvote if they answer again on the Canadian one. Once the person reaches the original upvote count I will delete the old answer to prevent duplicates.  The UK version has also been created [here](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/842/are-there-any-ebook-libraries-in-the-uk)

Answer (score 3):

I hesitate to delete answers, the site is young and many of our members have little rep at this time.

- This question can be clarified to be US centric.
- Leave the non-us answer, but encourage creation of separate questions by country and encourage new answers be posted there
- Owners of non-US answers can edit or delete non-US answers at their leisure. The answers were not "wrong" at the time they where posted.

No one is wrong here, we are growing as site, and it would be wrong to negatively impact anyone's rep for a developing scenario.

Comment: Rep should not be the primary consideration: beta is partially to soldify what a good question set looks like and doesn't look like. Perhaps going ahead and getting the other questions asked so that any good answers do have a home would be in order, but I wouldn't want to see non-answers left somewhere just so people earn rep.

Comment: Agree with Caleb. I'll vote up anybody who moves their answer to the right place!  And, umm, *vice-versa* ;-) [Not that I am able to downvote, yet.] p.s. I agree let's not equate "irrelevant" with "wrong". Nobody's answer was wrong.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea: I've started the process for the Canadian answer (and sent a message to the other Canadian answer poster).

Comment: It's a logical idea. Some people will have a problem with losing rep, but it's early days on this site, and it makes sense to separate such a question by geography. I've copied my response to the original question to the Canadian version.

Answer (score 1):

I am against one more question for every country, that way we could be ending up with a possible 190+ questions. Questions which might not even differ in answer if the county involves shares some über-country wide lending system with other countries.

The correct way to handle this kind of information that evolves over time is to change the US specific question in a generic one about ebook lending then create a wiki answer where the different countries can be added and update over time.

Comment: Only Canda & UK were created because the answer were allready posted.  No one was suggesting creating the other country questions.  Any new questions or answers not related to one of 3 countries we now have questions for come in, they should be on fresh country, question.